# React native Image cache without query parameters

Tags: javascript, react-native

paramOne and paramTwo values will change. This makes it so that the cached image won't be used and it will refetch the same image everytime since the url will be different.

Is there anyway to make it store the cache on

"https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/1/Img-Name.jpg"

and not

"https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/1/Img-Name.jpg?paramOne=ksjdfklsd&paramTwo=akjdklasd"?

```
<Image
    source={{
      uri:
        "https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/1/Img-Name.jpg?paramOne=ksjdfklsd&paramTwo=akjdklasd"
    }}
  />
```

Or do I have to use a third party component like react-native-cached-image?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load and store this image, no matter what are paramOne and paramTwo, why don't you just load the image with https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/1/Img-Name.jpg ? Any variable text will lead to the refetching of the image (my experience so far).

```
<Image
    source={{
      uri:
        "https://test.s3.amazonaws.com/1/Img-Name.jpg"
    }}
  />
```

To avoid reloading the image each time, you can use react-native-cached-image or [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image), which is really good.

Comment: The problem is that I need the parameters to grant access to the image

Comment: So you should check react-native-fast-image, there is the possibility to add custom header (`headers:{ Authorization: 'someAuthToken' }`). You can also considering using an API with a EC2 instance ! Are this params always changing for a same user ?

Comment: Yes the parameters are always chaning for the same user. I was hoping of not needing to use a third party component but looks like I have to.